# GDAL AllRegister

Tags: java, war, gdal

I am using the java gdal bindings in a web application. When I start the application I run a

```
gdal.AllRegister();
```

Which works fine until I decide to update my war file, ie when the new war reloads I get the following trace

```
Native library load failed.
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native Library /opt/gdal/lib/libgdaljni.so already loaded in another classloader
2017-07-26 15:58:31.920:WARN:oejd.DeploymentManager:Scanner-0: Unable to reach node goal: started
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.gdal.gdal.gdalJNI.AllRegister()V
        at org.gdal.gdal.gdalJNI.AllRegister(Native Method)
        at org.gdal.gdal.gdal.AllRegister(gdal.java:493)
```

I looked for some command to run when the context is destroyed, I tried the following for instance

```
gdal.GDALDestroyDriverManager();
```

But the result is the same.

Basically I need to reboot my server.

Is there a command I need to run to avoid this lock?

Thanks!